# looking for best barcode scanner library, besides zxing

Tags: android, iphone, symbian, barcode-scanner, zxing

I am looking for some best barcode libraries on all platforms. I know zxing but wondering more libraries besides it. Any help is appreciated~

Comment: You have tagged this question with Android, iOS, Symbian. You want one for each or you want just one for all ?

Comment: Nowadays, this question would be very much on-topic on [Software recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) - ***if*** it were to be reworded to give a list of requirements & features, rather than best/better than.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[Jeff Lamarche's Cocoa Barcodes project for iPhone and iPad](https://github.com/netshade/Cocoa-Touch-Barcodes)

[Zxing's barcode image process library](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/)

[Android barcode library](http://www.keepedge.com/products/android_barcode/)

[ISBN & QR Barcode Scanning Mobile App for Libraries](http://journal.code4lib.org/articles/5014)

Comment: https://github.com/EdwardvanRaak/MaterialBarcodeScanner

Answer (score 9):

As nithin mention Barcode scanner libraries, one more I would like to add ZBar Barcode Library.

http://zbar.sourceforge.net/

This also contains support for various platform. And it is Open Source.

Answer (score 2):

Scandit has a [Barcode Scanner SDK](http://www.scandit.com/barcode-scanner-sdk/) that is available for Android, iOS and Phonegap. There is a free community edition that scans UPC/EAN and QR codes. The SDK also works with fixed-focus cameras (such as on the iPad 2).

(Disclaimer: I'm a developer at Scandit.)

Comment: the license terms are not really OSS-friendly.

Answer (score 2):

Best PDF417 decoding library we've worked with by far was [Manatee Works](http://manateeworks.com/)'s library, already ported to most available mobile development platforms and cross-platform frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

For iPhone and Android both you can look into the below link:

This same works for both iPhone and Android.

http://shopsavvy.mobi/developers/

Hope this helps you.

Comment: @SeanOwen: Whats the problem you are facing with Zxing?

Comment: I'm not facing any problem (I'm the developer in fact) -- just noting that the OP seemed to want to try an alternative, and this library is mostly zxing inside too.