# How to integrate ZXing to AndroidApp with Maven?

Tags: android, maven, android-intent, zxing, qr-code

I'm writing an Android App and would like to include a QR-Code scanner to allow the Users the comfortable option of using these Codes without installing another App.

Because I'm building my Project with Maven I tried (as suggestet on the [project site](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/GettingStarted#Maven)) to include the ZXing Barcodescanner with the folloing code inside the *pom.xml*

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Unfortunately it did not work (I can't start the Intent *com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN*)

```
public void onButtonClick(View view) {
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
        intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR:"+e, 1).show();
    }
}
```

Does anyone got an idea how I can bring it alive? Or an alternative QR-Code Scanner?

-- Thank you

Comment: You're trying to use Intents, but you are trying to depend on the core library. These are mutually exclusive -- clarify your intent.

Answer (score 1):

Add as dependency [android-integration](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.google.zxing%7Candroid-integration%7C2.3.0%7Cjar) module:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
    <artifactId>android-integration</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Sadly the android-integration only prompts a dialog that allows the User to download the App. I'd like to provide it natively, so they don't have to download more Apps.

Comment: I understand you. As I am working with zxing - i'm always copying whole sourcecode inside my application, deleting unneeded stuff. It's surely uncomfortable, but grants modifying flexibility (e.g. change to portrait mode, etc) which may be needed in future.

Comment: Isn't there another possibility?
(I wanted to include it to make the work less :D)

Comment: As far as I know, no. Maybe it will be better decision to change zxing to other qr code lib.

Comment: check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116990/looking-for-best-barcode-scanner-library-besides-zxing

Comment: I found that one two, but you only can include JARs in these examples. I use Netbeans and qould like to include it via maven...

Comment: There exist possibility to add local libraries via maven.

Comment: Is there really no QRCode Scanner you can get with Maven for Android?

Comment: Thanks @Igorkonoplyanko I'll have a look at that but it sounds not nice :)